# Difference between env setup using custom webpack and dotenv

Tags: angular, environment-variables, dotenv

I was using `dotenv` for reading `.env` variables while development but it didn't work while building the project, then I encountered `custom webpack` to pass `.env` variables while building the project.

Now, I am confused, can I use `custom-webpack` to pass .env while I am just doing `ng serve`?
Am I even thinking right?
What is the actual difference between both mechanisms?

Comment: But dotenv works perfecr with ng build, maybe you have other issue that has not appearred yet

Comment: Can you point to a blog that explains this for the build environment, I was facing some weird errors and thought it won't work build.

Comment: I dont really know if there is any blog out there with that problem, it's the first time I see your error